# ReactJS, Context API) Read another component's state without passing down as prop to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have started learning basic of Context API in ReactJS.

This is a part of reactJS code which uses reactJS.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LeftPane from './LeftPane';
import RightPane from './RightPane';
import {SampleProvider} from './sample';
const App =()=>{
 return(
     <SampleProvider>
         <div className="panes">
             <LeftPane/>
             <RightPane/>
         </div>
     </SampleProvider>
   )
}
export default App;
ReactDOM.render(
   <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

RightPane.js

```
RightPane.js

import React from 'react';
import Receives from './Receives';

const RightPane =()=>{
  return(
      <div className="pane">
          <Receives/>
      </div>
  )
};

export default RightPane;
```

sample.js

```
import React,{Component , createContext} from 'react';

const Context = createContext();

const {Provider, Consumer : SampleConsumer}=Context;

class SampleProvider extends Component{
state={
    value:'default value'
}
actions={
    setValue:(value)=>{
        this.setState({value});
    }
}
render(){
    const {state,actions}=this;
    const value={state,actions};
    return(
        <Provider value={value}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Provider>
    )

}
}
export{
  SampleProvider,
  SampleConsumer
};
```

Receives.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {SampleConsumer} from './sample';
const Receives = ()=>{
 return(
     <SampleConsumer>
         { 
             (sample)=>(
                 <div>
                     Value:{sample.state.value}
                 </div>
             )

         }
     </SampleConsumer>
 )
}
console.log(Receives);
export default Receives;
```

Everything is fine. I understand everything except the function in SampleConsumer

component.

function in SampleConsumer uses sample as parameter.

I tested and sample.state.value renders 'default value' and it is the value of the state which is declared in SampleProvider component.

SampleProvider passes down the state as props to Provider component. I understand

Provider can use that state. But how the parameter in SampleConsumer understands

state in SampleProvider component? I have never passed the state as props to

SampleProvider component ..(I understood so. Maybe it's wrong)

I read this documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

but didn't understand 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything is fine. I understand everything except the function in SampleConsumer component.

You have set `SampleConsumer` to point to the raw `Consumer` output of `createContext()`. It will function exactly the same as the `ThemeContext.Consumer` example in the docs.

> function in SampleConsumer uses sample as parameter. I tested and sample.state.value renders 'default value' and it is the value of the state which is declared in SampleProvider component.

You have wrapped the raw `Provider` output of `createContext()` with your `SampleProvider` component. As you did so, you set the `Provider`'s context value to (initially) be:

```js
{
  state: {
    value: 'default value'
  },
  actions: {
    setValue: (value) => { this.setState({value}) }
  }
}
```

Meaning that whenever you invoke `SampleConsumer` that is a child of `SampleProvider`, the argument in the "child as a function" will be passed that value. In other words, this would display the string representation of the object in the above snippet:

```js
<SampleConsumer>
  { (value) => <div>{value.toString()}</div> }
</SampleConsumer>
```

> SampleProvider passes down the state as props to Provider component. I understand Provider can use that state.

Correct - you have set `Provider`'s `value` prop to be equal to an object that contains `SampleProvider`'s state.

> But how the parameter in SampleConsumer understands state in SampleProvider component?

This is exactly what the context API accomplishes. `SampleConsumer` has access to `Provider`'s `value` prop, without needing to pass the prop through all the child elements in between. Note that your code here doesn't have anything in between, so it's a little trivial; the docs you linked provide a better example.

> I have never passed the state as props to SampleProvider component ..(I understood so. Maybe it's wrong)

You passed `SampleProvider`'s state as a prop to `Provider`. `Provider`, in turn, passed its prop down to `SampleConsumer`.

I think the core of the misunderstanding here is your use (or naming) of `SampleProvider`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that state, but it's not really a "Provider" anymore and makes things confusing. This is unlike your `SampleConsumer`, which is still the default `Consumer`, just renamed.